# Entire functions of order 0

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, analyticity

Sorry, this may be a stupid question, but I am just beginning to learn about this and cannot find the answer anywhere I have looked so far. Clearly if we have any polynomial $P(z)$, then it is easy to show that the order is $0$.

Clearly though not all entire functions that grow at roughly this rate are polynomials as I believe $\sin (z)$ is of order $1$, which would make $f(z) = \frac {\sin (z)}{e^z}$ an entire function of order $0$.

It is obvious that $f$ still has infinitely many $0$'s and is thus not a polynomial.

I was wondering what the characterization of all entire functions of $0$-order look like. I would assume it will just be all functions with $0$'s that are "nicely" spaced. But I do not know how to make this precise exactly as I know very little about this subject material. If anyone wants to aid me in my studies it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: My friend pointed out that $\frac {\sin z}{e^z}=e^{-z} \sin z$, which grows at least as fast as $\sin z$ for large negative real values of $z$. So I'm confused... are there non-polynomial entire functions of order $0$ or not? And how can we see this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many non-polynomial entire functions of order zero. You can show that the order $\rho$ can be computed as
$$
\rho = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\log n}{\log(1/|a_n|)}
$$
where $a_n$ are the Maclaurin coefficients of $f$. To get a function of order $0$, you only have to make sure that $|a_n|$ tends sufficiently fast to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. For example,
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2} z^n
$$
has order $0$ (and is clearly not a polynomial).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I figured it out. It just follows from the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem for entire functions of finite order that it will have the normal form for an entire function just that the polynomial over the $e$ will be degree 0, or in other words a constant and will have all the roots multiplied by $e^{poly(z/z^n)}$.