# Entire function of a given order

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi i was reading through the book "Einführung in die analytische Zahlentheorie" by Brüdern and got stuck on an exercise. The order of a complex entire function f is defined as $\inf \lbrace \alpha > 0 : f(z)\in O(e^{|z|^\alpha})\rbrace $. For any given real alpha I have to construct an entire function of a given order.  The problem I have is that the most straight forward approach, defining f as $e^{z^\alpha}$ doesnt work, because $z^{\alpha}$ is not entire. To construct a function of any given rational order it should be enough to construct a function of order 1/n. Also working with other complex functions i know is kinda difficult, because I have very little intuition for how something like $(s-1)\zeta (s)$ behaves, when $s<1$.

Comment: The classical Weierstrass product approach would be to use an infinite product like $\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-\frac z{z_k}) e{p(z/z_k)}$ where the sequence $|z_k|$ grows at a certain rate (tailored to the $\alpha$ you want) and $p$ is a certain polynomial.

Comment: other standard examples are $\sum e^{-n^2}z^n$ in $0$ order and $\sum (1/n)^{n/\alpha} z^n$ order $\alpha >0$

Comment: for rational order $p/q$ one can take any order $1$ function like $e^z$, symmetrize it with $q$ roots of unity so take $qg(z)=\sum_{w^q=1} f(wz)$ and then $g(z)=\sum a_nz^{nq}$ so one can do $g(z^{p/q})=h(z)=\sum a_nz^{np}$ which has order $p/q$; for example $\cos \sqrt z$ makes sense and has order $1/2$

Comment: In your definition of the order, $e^{|z|*\alpha}$ should be be replaced by $e^{|z|^\alpha}.$

Answer (score 1):

For each $\alpha > 0$ is the [Mittag-Leffler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function)
$$
 E_{\alpha, 1}(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{z^n}{\Gamma(\alpha n + 1)}
$$
an entire function of order $1/\alpha$.

This follows from the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type)
$$ \tag{$*$}
\rho = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \log(n)}{-\log|a_n|}
$$
for the order of an entire function in terms of its Taylor coefficients, and [Stirling's approximation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling%27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function) for the Gamma function.

The same formula $(*)$ can be used to construct entire functions of order zero, see for example

- [Entire functions of order 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236603/entire-functions-of-order-0/1237098#1237098)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another classical example:

$$g_\alpha(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{z^n}{(n!)^\alpha}$$

where $\alpha>0$. It is easy to check that $f_\alpha$ is entire. On the other hand
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\frac{R^n}{(n!)^\alpha}&=\frac12\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{2^n}\Big(\frac{R^{n/\alpha}}{n!}\Big)^\alpha \\
&<\frac12\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{2^n}e^{\alpha R^{1/\alpha}}=e^{\alpha R^{1/\alpha}}
\end{align}

Hence (setting $R=2|z|$)
$$|g_\alpha(z)|< 2 \exp\big(\alpha 2^{1/\alpha}|z|^{1/\alpha}\big)$$
Thus means that $g_\alpha$ is of finite order $\rho_*=\rho(g_\alpha)\leq 1/\alpha$.

Let $a_n:=\frac{1}{(n!)^\alpha}$. Suppose $\beta>\alpha$ so that $\rho=\frac{1}{\beta}<\frac{1}{\alpha}$. Since $\frac{1}{n!}>\frac{1}{n^n}$,
$$ n^\beta|a_n|^{1/n}>n^\beta\frac{1}{n^\alpha}=n^{\beta-\alpha}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$$

It follows that $g_\alpha$ is indeed of order $\rho_*=1/\alpha$.