# Want an example of entire function of order $\sqrt 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, entire-functions

I want an example of entire function with order $\sqrt 2$.

If $f$ is a entire function of finite order $\rho$ then $\rho=\lim_{R \to \infty} \sup_{r \geq R} \frac{\log \log M(f,r)}{\log(r)}$, where $M(f,r)=\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$.

Take $f(z)=e^{z^{\sqrt 2}}$, then $M(f,r)=\max_{|z|=r}|e^{z^{\sqrt 2}}|=e^{r^{\sqrt 2}}$ for any $r>0$. Thus by the above formula $$\rho(f)=\sup_{r} \frac{\log \log (e^{r^{\sqrt 2}})}{\log r}=\sup_{r} \frac{\log (r^{\sqrt 2}\log e)}{\log r}=\sup_{r} \frac{\log (r^{\sqrt 2})}{\log r}=\sup_{r} \frac{\sqrt 2\log r}{\log r}=\sqrt 2.$$

So I think this serves as an example of entire function of order $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: how do you define $z^{\sqrt 2}$ as an entire function? You need a branch of the logarithm. Your example is incorrect. Something like $\sum_{n \ge 1} (\frac{1}{n})^{n/\sqrt 2}z^n$ works (why?)

Comment: You could try to show that it is holomorphic but you will have a hard time describing the coefficients...

Comment: @Conrad, sorry, we can not take irrational exponent

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean; the defintion of the series is correct as $(\frac{1}{n})^{n/\sqrt 2}=e^{-n \log n/\sqrt 2}$ - if you prefer you can take rational numbers $a_n \to \sqrt 2$ and do $\sum_{n \ge 1} (\frac{1}{n})^{n/a_n}z^n$ as the result is same; in a way or another you need to use the defintion of the order using the coefficient formula ($\limsup \frac{n\log n}{-\log |c_n|}$

Comment: @Conrad, in my previous comment, I meant $z^n$ and $e^{z^n}$ is entire, where $n$ is positive integer, we can not take $n$ an irrational number. Sorry for incomplete language expression

Comment: @Conrad, is $\lim \sup \frac{n \log n}{-\log |c_n|}$ the formula for the order, for entire function with power series representation ?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4724876/121671) is a relatively well known example of an entire function $g_\alpha$  of order $1/\alpha$: $g_\alpha(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{z^n}{(n!)^\alpha}$.