# Find a non-polynomial entire function $f(z)$ such that $|f(z)| \leq e^{A|z|^{\alpha}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I have to find a non-polynomial entire function $f(z)$ such that $|f(z)| \leq e^{A|z|^{\alpha}}$ where  $A \gt 0$ and $\alpha \lt \frac{1}{2}$.

I tried to insert $z = 0$ and I get $|f(0)| \leq e^{A|0|^{\alpha}} = 1$, so I would look at a function which maps $0$ inside the closed unit disc. Looking at the form of the inequality, I would assume that a function of the form $e^z$ would be a candidate, firstly because it is not a polynomial function. But I don't know how to exactly determine the function $f(z)$

Comment: Your "candidate" $e^z$ is expelled: $|e^z|$ is not $\le e^{A|z|^{1/2}}.$

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4482370/42969

Comment: @AnneBauval I'm not really sure how to apply it to my case.

Comment: The answer says that the Mittag-Leffler entire function $f(z):=E_{1/\alpha,1}(z)$ is of order $\alpha,$ i.e. $\alpha=\inf \lbrace \lambda > 0 : f(z)\in O(e^{|z|^\lambda})\rbrace.$ This solves your problem.

Comment: @AnneBauval oh, okay. Thanks! But the problem is we didn't said anything about the Mittag-Leffler entire function in our course. I think only about the theorem (if even that)

Comment: Even simpler: [Entire functions of order 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236603/entire-functions-of-order-0/1237098#1237098).

Comment: another simple way to construct examples is to take a known function of order $1$ like $e^z$ and symmetrize it so it is a power series only in $z^n, n \ge 3$ - eg $f(z)=(e^z+e^{\omega z}+e^{\omega^2 z})/3, \omega^3=1$ works for $3$ and using $\pm z, \pm iz$ works for $4$ etc then $f(z^{1/3})$ which makes sense and is entire (or if you prefer replacing $z^3$ by $z$ in the Taylor series) is easily shown to work for you with $\alpha=1/3$ etc

Comment: @Conrad thank You for the reply! But I don't really understand, what exactly is the order? How do I determine it?

Comment: Order is your $\alpha$ (more or less as there are a few subtleties); for $e^z$ is fairly clear $1$ by definition